# After adding new column to table my EF query throws error " Unknown column 'Extent2.User_UserId' in 'field list' "

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

My database in **mysql**. everything was working properly until i added new column to my table **CustomTagUser**. The new column is also another **FK** from **User Table** which is **OwnerId** .

```
public class CustomTagUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomTagUserId { get; set; }
        public int CustomTagId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; } // newly added column
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomTagId")]
        public virtual CustomTags CustomTags { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OwnerId")] // added for navigation 
        public virtual User Owner { get; set; } // added for navigation 
    }

public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserSetting> UserSettings { get; set; }        
        public ICollection<UserRoles> Roles { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserPreference> Preference { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CustomTagUser> CustomTagUser { get; set; }

    }
```

When I hit following query it says  **Unknown column 'Extent2.User_UserId'** in 'field list' Which was completely running fine before adding new column. Also If I remove Owner property it will not throw the error but Then I won't be able to load referenced data to that OwnerId.

```
var userDetail = dbContext.Users.Include(x => x.CustomTagUser.Select(y => y.CustomTags)).FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == peopleId);
```

I don't know what I did wrong. Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `add-migration` then `update-database`

Comment: I do this manually, But safer side I dropped the table and recreated with required new column as I m in development phase only for this table

Comment: For a cleaner way, I suggest to drop the database, delete all migration files, and re-run those commands :)

Comment: I suggest that because your model is correct and should work

Comment: TBH my project do not have any migration script. As I said I do it manually. create db table & create model class , apply data annotation & it;s done

Comment: Can you please add a capture of the tables you created? It seems that some solumns do not follow the convetions maybe.